# How to make only one child element sticky without affecting the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

The relevant elements in the code below are `.top`, `.sticky` and `.other`.

`.sticky` and `.other` are sitting inside the `.navbar` container.

Now, making the whole `.navbar` sticky is easy. Adding `position: sticky; top: 0;` to that element does that. That's the general behavior I want.

The challenge I'm facing is:

How to make **only** the `.sticky` element sticky so that everything underneath will always scroll underneath it?

If you run the current code, you can see that the `.sticky` element only remains sticky until the yellow `.other` element has scrolled underneath it. After that the `.sticky` element stops being sticky.

That's the problem I'm trying to solve. How to keep the blue `.sticky` element always sticky? (after you scroll up to the point where the green `.top` part becomes hidden)

**Ideally looking for a css-only solution**. If that's not possible, a JavaScript/jQuery solution would be acceptable but has to work properly when scrolling in both directions up or down.

UPDATE:

I know that taking the yellow `.other` element out of the header would solve the problem. But the problem is that the yellow `.other` element needs to be part of the header. Both `.sticky` and `.other` need to be displayed next to each other on large screens and under each other on mobile screens. That's why they are currently child elements inside another container. So, moving the yellow element out of the header is not really an option I could use in this case.

```css
.top {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
.navbar {
/*            position: sticky;*/
/*            top: 0;*/
}
.sticky {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.other {
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: darkgray;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
   Top
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <header class="navbar">
       <div class="header-container">
           <div id="row-masthead">
               <div class="sticky">
                   Sticky
               </div>
               <div class="other">
                   Other
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <main class="content">
      <h2>
          Content
      </h2>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
   </main>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
   <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `postion:fixed` ?

Comment: @Soothran I wouldn't have the **sticky** behavior with `position: fixed`, would I? I'm looking for the behavior that you get with `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to consider the use of [`display:contents`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) in the containers of the sticky elements to make them like they don't exist and you will have what you want:

```css
.top {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
.navbar,
.header-container,
#row-masthead{
  display:contents /* added this */
}
.sticky {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.other {
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: darkgray;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
   Top
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <header class="navbar">
       <div class="header-container">
           <div id="row-masthead">
               <div class="sticky">
                   Sticky
               </div>
               <div class="other">
                   Other
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <main class="content">
      <h2>
          Content
      </h2>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
   </main>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
   <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
</div>
```

Another *hacky* solution is to create the needed space the sticky element using a combination of height and negative margin like below. The drawback is that you need to find the correct value to avoid creating a lot of space at the bottom and to have the needed space for the sticky.

```css
.top {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
div#row-masthead:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 200vh; /*big value here*/
}
div#row-masthead {
  margin-bottom:-200vh; /*same value here*/
}

.sticky {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.other {
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: darkgray;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
   Top
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <header class="navbar">
       <div class="header-container">
           <div id="row-masthead">
               <div class="sticky">
                   Sticky
               </div>
               <div class="other">
                   Other
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <main class="content">
      <h2>
          Content
      </h2>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
   </main>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
   <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
</div>
```

With some JS you can dynamically and correctly calculate the value:

```js
var h = document.querySelector('.middle').offsetHeight - document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;

document.querySelector('#row-masthead').style.setProperty("--h", h+"px");

window.onresize = function(event) {
    h = document.querySelector('.middle').offsetHeight - document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
    document.querySelector('#row-masthead').style.setProperty("--h", h+"px");
}
```

```css
.top {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
div#row-masthead:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: var(--h,0);
}
div#row-masthead {
  margin-bottom:calc(-1*var(--h,0));
}

.sticky {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.other {
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: darkgray;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
   Top
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <header class="navbar">
       <div class="header-container">
           <div id="row-masthead">
               <div class="sticky">
                   Sticky
               </div>
               <div class="other">
                   Other
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <main class="content">
      <h2>
          Content
      </h2>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
   </main>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
   <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Love your solutions. I guess we'll have to wait a little until older browsers disappear so that `display: contents` could be used without worries.

Comment: Can you explain the thinking behind the JS solution?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I will favorite this answer to remember the 100K action ;) ... for the JS the idea is to calculate the missing content inside the middle part. If you want the element to stick inside the middle part then the missing height will be `height of the middle part - height of the actual stikcy container` and the actual sticky container is the navbar. You can find the height with different formula. You simply need to find where is the missing height you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from **position:sticky**, you would have to redefine your HTML structure  and move element with class .other out of the header. And also, uncomment your css code regarding the .navbar class.

Something like this:

```css
.top {
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: darkgreen;
}
.navbar {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
}
.sticky {
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.other {
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    background-color: lightgray;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: darkgray;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="top">
  Top
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
  <header class="navbar">
   <div class="header-container">
    <div id="row-masthead">
     <div class="sticky">
      Sticky
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>

  <div class="other">
   Other
  </div>
  
  <main class="content">
     <h2>
      Content
     </h2>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
  </main>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
  </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I know that would be an option. The problem is that the yellow `.other` element needs to be part of the header. `.sticky` and `.other` need to be displayed next to each other on large screens and under each other on mobile screens. That's why they are currently child elements inside another container.

Comment: If you want them to be side by side when in smaller screens, you can use some css grid and css variables to have that effect. Take a look at :  https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/vYByebw , it seems like you can have the effect you want just with some small changes :)

Comment: The reason for my original HTML structure was to add the `sticky` property to the whole header on large screens so that both blue and yellow elements are acting like one sticky element. Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with your approach?

Comment: Sure there is, if I understood what you wanted, the desired behaviour was updated in the codepen. https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/vYByebw 
And this way, the html structure, did not change.

Comment: And now, with this last post of yours, we are back to where the started. That's the problem I'm facing. The yellow part on mobile needs to behave like the grey content part underneath but on desktop yellow and blue need to be sticky as one. That's the problem!

Comment: Ok, I really hope this is the final version. So, it behaves with sticky blue and yellow on desktop. And it behaves with sticky only on blue in mobile, with 2 columns. 

https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/BaBQJNY

Comment: Hmm... are you sure you posted the right link? Because that codepen version seems to combine the problems of the previous ones.

Comment: Well yes, if it's not correct, that's because I'm defently miss understanding what you are trying to achieve :s

Comment: The objective is: "sticky" behavior (i.e. behavior normally achieved by `position: sticky; top: 0;`) for the whole header section on desktop but on mobile only the blue `.sticky` section needs to be sticky (i.e. can't be influenced by the yellow part).

Answer (score 0):

check the following code, it may help you. Check it into full page or full screen mode, in the desktop mode sticky and other sections are side by side and in mobile view other div is under the sticky div. It needs media queries for mobile view.

```css
.top 
 { min-height: 40px; background-color: darkgreen; }
 
 .navbar { height:auto;  }

 .sticky {
  min-height: 90px; background-color: lightblue;
  width:50%; float:left;
 }
 
 .row_masthead
 { position: fixed; top: 0; width:100%; }
 
 .other {
  min-height: 90px; background-color: yellow;
  width:50%; float:left;
 }

 .content {
  background-color: lightgray; min-height: 600px;
  margin-top:4%;
 }
 
 .bottom { background-color: darkgray; min-height: 200px; }
 
 @media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)
 {
  .sticky 
  { width:100%; }
  
  .other 
  { width:100%; float:left; } 
  
  .content
  { margin-top:43%; }
 }
```

```html
<div class="top">
   Top
</div>
<div class="middle">
   <header class="navbar">
       <div class="header-container">
           <div id="row-masthead" class="row_masthead">
               <div class="sticky">
                   Sticky
               </div>
               <div class="other">
                   Other
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <main class="content">
      <h2>
          Content
      </h2>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
       <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
       </p>
   </main>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
   <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus non vero quam suscipit veniam ex praesentium id sunt, voluptatibus ad ipsa asperiores enim quis omnis alias maxime saepe aut. Iste.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the green `.top` section? Why don't you just run your code to see the problems with it? I mean, that's what the "run code snippet" feature is for! I clearly stated that `.top` is one of the relevant sections. You can't just hide it. Please re-read my question a couple of times to understand what the problem is.